# Best practices when using POSTin Symfony 2

Tags: jquery, post, symfony

My question is simple: When using Symfony 2 and jQuery.post should I include the parameters in the route or post to an static url and send the parameters in the body of the request?

```
$.post('/article/delete/5', function(e){
    // Do something
});
```

OR:

```
$.post('/article/delete', { id : 5 }, function(e){
    // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former, if you look at a RESTful API the resource ID is always included in the URI if you want to get (GET), update (PUT), delta update (PATCH) or delete it (DELETE). In an ideal world however you would make a DELETE request using jQuery.

```
$.ajax('/article/delete/5', {
    'type': 'DELETE'
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/